# Java - Multi-Threaded Socket Server, How to check a clients connection to the server?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, arraylist, synchronization

I am wondering how to check if a client is still connected to a server, like to see if the client has crashed, and if not, to check its ping to the server. Im adding all new clients to an ArrayList and when they crash I want to know how to remove them from the list so that I can keep things clean. Im not sure how to do this with Synchronization or if thats possible. If there is a better way too control my threads any advice is welcomed, thanks.

SERVER CODE:

```
package Main;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MultiThreadedServer implements Runnable{

private static List<Thread> clients = new ArrayList<Thread>();

Socket cs;
private static ServerSocket ss;
private static int port = 25570;

MultiThreadedServer(Socket cs){
    this.cs = cs;
}
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    try{
        ss = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Server Listening"); 
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Port Taken");
    }

    while(true){
        Socket newClient = ss.accept();
        System.out.println(newClient.getInetAddress() + " Has Connected");
        Thread client = new Thread(new MultiThreadedServer(newClient));
        client.start();
        clients.add(client);
        System.out.println("Connected Clients: " + clients.size());
    }
}
public void run(){
    try{
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(cs.getOutputStream());
        ps.println("Welcome Client #" + clients.size());
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

CLIENT CODE:

```
package Main;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Client{

private static String ip = "127.0.0.1";
private static int port = 25570;

public static void main(){

    Socket socket;
    BufferedReader reader;
    PrintWriter writer;

    try {
        socket = new Socket(ip,port);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        OutputStreamWriter os = new 
OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(os);

        System.out.println(in.readLine());
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR UNKNOWN");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not connect to server!");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The thread serving the connection on the server, it sends the welcome message and falls out. The client prints it and falls out. They're not connected anymore, they just take up a socket because they haven't closed it

Comment: @LevKuznetsov I dont quite understand, how would i keep them connected?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you want to communicate over the socket?

Comment: @LevKuznetsov Currently a chat server, i am just trying to learn multi-threading and sockets.

Comment: Then you need to write code to wait on messages and dispatch them. Start with the client, how are you going to read the second message? And third?